# Is there any JSF or Primefaces Photo tagger component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, photo-tagging

Is there any built-in component for facebook like photo-tagging in JSF(Preferably in Primefaces). Or will it be in near future? I have googled a lot but found nothing -- I found a lot of jQuery photo taggers, but I am not good at jQuery, I am unable to submit tag values to the JSF in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use the jQuery-photo-tagger (believe me, it's worth looking into jQuery) and use the PrimeFaces Ajax-API to make your ajax-calls. The basic functionality is:

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(url, config, parameters);
```

A little more complex example would be:

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(‘/myapp/createUser.jsf’,
{
formId:’userForm’,
,source:’userForm’
,process:’userForm’
,update:’msgs’
oncomplete:function(xhr, status) {alert(‘Done’);}   
},
{
‘param_name1’:’value1’,
‘param_name2’:’value2’
}
);
```

For more information you can have a look at the User Guide: http://primefaces.org/documentation.html (starting from page 420)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction, I am into it, and successfully ran a sample project -- Hope to successfully incorporate it into my real project -- Thanks again

Comment: This gave me an interesting idea like p:imageTagger :)

Comment: @CagatayCivici When do you think this idea is going to be realized :)